# JPA relationship entity updated on database but not on site

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

I've got Product and Rating entities in JPA.

In Product.java:

```
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="rating_id")
@JsonManagedReference("product-rating")
private Rating rating;
```

In Rating.java:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="rating",cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JsonBackReference("product-rating")
private Product product;
```

In my JPAService implementation:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updateCartLineRating(CartLine cartLine, int rating) {
cartLine.setRating(rating);
    em.merge(cartLine);

    Product product = cartLine.getProduct();
    Rating productRatingObject = product.getRating();

    // Here I calculate new rating, then I set it:

    productRatingObject.setRating(productRating);

    // I associate the new Rating to Product (which is the relationship owner) and viceversa

    productRatingObject.setProduct(product);
    product.setRating(productRatingObject);

    em.merge(product);

}
```

When I do that, my database is updated, while my views are not. I have to restart the server to make these changes appear.

I tried to write `em.refresh(product);` after `em.merge(product);` but I get this error:

> Can not refresh not managed object: package.Product@33891d5d

I'm making confusion and I don't know how to solve this problem. Could you please help me?

Comment: so if you `find()` the product its not updated?

Comment: Try implementing `equals() and hashcode()` and try just refetching the entity with `find()`

Comment: @KevinBowersox if I find() the Product, I get the correct values. What do you mean with "implementing equals and hashcode()"?

Comment: The persistence provider may be relying upon Java's version of identity (checking for same object in memory) as opposed to actually comparing the fields to determine if the entity already exists.  To make the persistence provider check equality using fields you implement `equals` and `hashcode` which are overridden methods that provide comparison logic.  Are you using eclipse? I can walk you through it.  I can't guarantee it will resolve the issue, but I think there is a good chance it may.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `entityManager` to find the entity again.  This should provide the entity with updated values.

Comment: I don't get it. If I find() the product I get the correct updated values, but I want the jsp to retrieve them as usual. I don't think I've understood what you're suggesting

Comment: On the server side `find` the entity after the `merge`.  Then add the entity to the request (or model if using Spring MVC).  Then you can access the rating via the JSP using the expression language.

Comment: I should create a method only for this, and call it via controller...it seems a bit odd. I think there's something else wrong in my code

Comment: @KurtBourbaki I am not aware of your application's structure, but I assume the method you posted in the example is called by a controller?  Within that controller method is where I would refetch the entity.  I may be assuming the structure of your application incorrectly or where this method is being called.  Provide some more context if you need additional help.  For example, I do not know how your sending the object to the jsp for display.